# What happens when you try to move a file to a non-existant location MAC?

Tags: macos, file, mv

On executing the following lines via the terminal on a MAC,
    mv terraform2 ~/bin
    cd ~/bin
I get the error that '/Users/myname/bin: Not a directory`.  However, I can't see the file terraform2 in its original location.  Where did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
 mv terraform2 ~/bin
```

If `~/bin` doesn't exist before you run that command, your file `terraform2` will be renamed to a **file** called `~/bin`.

Thus, when you try

```
cd ~/bin
```

you get

```
/Users/myname/bin: Not a directory
```

because it's a **file** - your original `terraform2` file.

The command

```
 mv terraform2 ~/bin/.
```

is much better when you're trying to `mv` a file into a directory.